# Getting twisted.defer.CancelledError when using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

Whenever I run the scrapy crawl command the following error props up:

```
2016-03-12 00:16:56 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://XXXXXXX/rnd/sites/default/files/Agreement%20of%20FFCCA(1).pdf>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 246, in _cb_bodyready
    raise defer.CancelledError()
CancelledError
2016-03-12 00:16:56 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://XXXXXX/rnd/sites/default/files/S&P_Chemicals,etc.20150903.doc>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 246, in _cb_bodyready
    raise defer.CancelledError()
CancelledError
```

I have tried searching on the internet on this error, but to no benefit.

My crawler code is given below:

```py
import os
import StringIO
import sys
import scrapy
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class IntSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "intranetspidey"
    allowed_domains = ["*****"]
    start_urls = [
        "******"
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_extensions=["ppt","pptx"],deny=(r'.*\?.*') ),
             follow=True,
             callback='parse_webpage'),
    )


    def get_pdf_text(self, response):
        """ Peek inside PDF to check possible violations.
        @return: PDF content as searcable plain-text string
        """
        try:
                from pyPdf import PdfFileReader
        except ImportError:
                print "Needed: easy_install pyPdf"
                raise 
        stream = StringIO.StringIO(response.body)
        reader = PdfFileReader(stream)
        text = u""

        if reader.getDocumentInfo().title:
                # Title is optional, may be None
                text += reader.getDocumentInfo().title

        for page in reader.pages:
                # XXX: Does handle unicode properly?
                text += page.extractText()

        return text 

    def parse_webpage(self, response):

        ct = response.headers.get("content-type", "").lower()
        if "pdf" in ct or ".pdf" in response.url:
            data = self.get_pdf_text(response)

        elif "html" in ct:
              do something
```

I am just starting out with Scrapy and I would be highly grateful for your knowledgeable solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - simple! :)

Just open [the source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py#L307) where the error is thrown... seems like the page is more than `maxsize`... which leads us [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-maxsize).

So, the problem is that you're trying to get large documents. Increase the `DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE` limit in settings and you should be fine.

Note: Your performance will suffer because you're blocking the CPU to do PDF decoding and while this happens no further requests will be issued. Scrapy's architecture is strictly single-threaded. Here are two (out of many) solutions:

a) Use the [file pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-files-pipeline) to download the files and then batch-process them with some other system.

b) Use `reactor.spawnProcess()` and use separate processes for PDF decoding. ([see here](https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook/blob/master/ch09/properties/properties/pipelines/legacy.py#L16)). This allows you to use Python or any other command line tool to do PDF decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a line like this in your output/log something like:

```
Expected response size X larger than download max size Y.
```

It sounds like the response you are requesting is more than 1GB. Your error is coming from the [download handler](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.0.5/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py#L246) which [defaults to one gig](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-maxsize) but can be [overridden](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#populating-the-settings) easily in:

- Project `settings.py` file with [DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-maxsize),
- spider's [`custom_settings`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.custom_settings) with `download_maxsize` or
- a manual [Request meta key](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) of `download_maxsize`.